# I don't have Mavic Air 2 camera image on my IPhone

Tags: dji, dji-mavic-air-2

Recently, I updated my IPhone DJI Fly app to the latest version, and all of a sudden there's no image from the drone's camera on the app, I have even tried multiple devices, nothing.

That's while I have my Mavic Air 2 working and fully operational on Android devices. Good to know that there is no errors showing on my screen when I connect my IPhone to the controller.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  For clarity, when you say "multiple devices," you mean multiple IPhones or multiple Mavics?

Comment: Also it would be great if you could include the version number of the app for reference.  Thanks!